# Declaring variable with name `this` inside lambda inside parentheses leads to different results on 3 different compilers

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

In C++ it's possible to declare variable inside parentheses like `int (x) = 0;`. But it seems that if you use `this` instead of variable name, then constructor is used instead: `A (this);` calls `A::A(B*)`. So the first question is why it's different for `this`, is it because variables can't be named `this`? And to complicate matters a bit lets put `this` inside a lambda -

```
struct B;
struct A
{
  A (B *) {}
};

struct B 
{
  B ()
  {
    [this] { A (this); } ();
  }
};
```

Now gcc calls `A::A(B*)`, msvc prints error about missing default constructor and clang prints `expected expression` (https://godbolt.org/g/Vxe0fF). It's even funnier in msvc - it really creates variable with name `this` that you can use, so it's definitely a bug (https://godbolt.org/g/iQaaPH). Which compiler is right and what are the reasons for such behavior?

Comment: `this` is a reserved identifier, you cannot declare it.

Comment: @n.m. Yes, the question is what is supposed to happen - calling constructor or compiler error because of `this` being reserved

Comment: I don't see how A(this) is different from A(5).

Comment: @n.m. Inside lambda `this` is just a member variable, so `A(this)` is no different from `A (x)`. At least 2 compilers are wrong anyway so it's not so simple.

Comment: No it isn't. It is a reserved word. Inside a lambda it is adjusted to refer to the unnamed member variable, but it *is not* that member variable.

Comment: @n.m. So the correct one is gcc and constructor should be called?

Comment: It looks like gcc is right, kinda obviously. BTW clang 3.9.1 doesn't produce an error either, you just forgot -std=c++11.

Comment: EDG agrees with GCC and Clang (`this` is a keyword). Using `A(this)` outside of a lambda works in MSVC as well. You should report the lambda case as a bug. cc @n.m.

Comment: @n.m.: `A(5)` can't be parsed as a declaration, and unambiguously is an expression. `A(token);` however can be parsed as the declaration of `token`, defining a local variable `token`. And this parse takes precedence. It breaks down for `A(this)` because you can't define a local variable `this`.

Comment: @MSalters It also breaks down for `A(5)` because you can't define a local variable `5`. What's the difference? `this` is not a possible variable name, neither is `5`, while `token` is.

Comment: @MSalters `5` is a token - a *literal* token. `this` is also a token - a *keyword* token. `some_var` is also a token - an *identifier* token (see [\[lex.token\]](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.token)). Only the latter kind can syntactically appear in a declaration like `A(token);`. The grammar doesn't allow `A(this);` to be a declaration, so I don't think this needs the ambiguity resolution rules in [stmt.ambig]; it's syntactically unambiguous. The note in [\[stmt.ambig\]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.ambig#2) is relevant as well.

Answer (score 1):

In the C++ standard §5.1.5 (article 7 for C++11, article 8 later standard) [expr.prim.lambda]:

> The lambda-expression’s compound-statement yields the function-body (8.4) of the function call operator, but
>   for purposes of name lookup (3.4), determining the type and value of this (9.2.2.1) and transforming id-
>   expressions referring to non-static class members into class member access expressions using (*this) (9.2.2),
>   the compound-statement is considered in the context of the lambda-expression. [ Example:

```
struct S1 {
  int x, y;
  int operator()(int);
  void f() {
    [=]()->int {
      return operator()(this->x + y); // equivalent to S1::operator()(this->x + (*this).y)
                                      // this has type S1*
               };
  }
};
```

> — end example ]

Thus, gcc is right. You will notice that their is no exception about the fact that you are capturing `this`. Their is, however a precision since C++14 in the case where you capture `*this`, still in §5.1.5 (article 17):

> If *this is captured by copy, each odr-use of this is transformed into a pointer to the corresponding
>   unnamed data member of the closure type, cast (5.4) to the type of this.